# Fill non-transparent part of image in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, transparency, png, fill

I have a linked image in Adobe InDesign which is a transparent PNG. I want to fill the visible part of that image with a particular color, i.e. the transparent pieces should stay transparent but the non-transparent pieces should be of this one color. That is, I want to only use its shape.

I tried playing around with *Object → Clipping Path,* but I do not want any detection of sorts, and I don’t know what *threshold* and *tolerance* do, as for me it is pretty clearly *all transparent pixels* vs. *all non-transparent pixels.* Also I do not know how to then only fill that path.

Comment: I'm not certain it's possible to use a PNG as an inverted mask in InDesign.

Comment: Not really what ID is made for. You can do this in PS, link in ID.